# Updating environment object causes memory to keep growing with each update

Tags: swift, macos, memory-leaks

I created a new app representing a similar case I had in an actual app. Basically, I'm updating the value of an observable object, which is used to render the UI. And for some reason that causes the memory to keep growing with each iteration. I also noticed that the amount of how much the memory grows depends on how many iterations/second and the number/type of views in the ContentView.

Note: The observable object being updated is `self.infoObj.text = "Counter: \(counter)"`

*AppDelgate.swift*

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    infoObj = InfoObj()

    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()
        .environmentObject(infoObj)

    // Create the window and set the content view. 
    window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.center()
    window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    
    var counter = 0;
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        while(true) {
            usleep(1000)
            counter += 1
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.infoObj.text = "Counter: \(counter)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*ContentView.swift*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var infoObj: InfoObj
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Text 11")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 12")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 13")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 14")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 15")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            Text(infoObj.text)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            HStack {
                Text("Text 21")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 22")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 23")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 24")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 25")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Text 31")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 32")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 33")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 34")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 35")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Text 41")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 42")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 43")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 44")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 45")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Text 51")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 52")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 53")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 54")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text("Text 55")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class InfoObj: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = "initial"
}
```

Could you help me understand the reason why this happens? And how I can solve it?  Also, why isn't this caught as a memory leak by code instruments?

Answer (score 1):

You just cycled execution synchronously on stack so you observe stack growing (which is not handled as leaked memory).

The solution is to make instead asynchronous counter handling and move everything into EnvironmentObject

```
class InfoObj: ObservableObject {
    private var counter = 0
    @Published var text = "initial" {
        didSet {
            print(">> " + text)   // << used for testing
        }
    }

    func runCounter() {
        counter += 1
        text = "Counter: \(self.counter)"

        // !! There is no sense to update UI with 1 milisecond 
        // (but you can tune interval below as you need)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05, execute: runCounter)
    }
}
```

and use

```
    // ... other code
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    infoObj.runCounter()      // << here !!    
}
```

Comment: Isn't the `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async` block enough to execute asynchronously? The thing is my actual app isn't just a simple counter, but rather a value brought over TCP and is expected to update multiple times per second.

Comment: Also, even when I change `DispatchQueue.main.sync { self.infoObj.text = "Counter: \(counter)" }` to `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.infoObj.text = "Counter: \(counter)" }` I still get the same issue.

Comment: ok, actually no, using `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.infoObj.text = "Counter: \(counter)" }` seems to solve this. Another question, is there a way to force free the memory if I go with the `sync` option?